# Deactivating and reactivating plugins on-the-fly

Tags: overrides, plugin, setup-di-compile, interceptor, di.xml

I am currently developing on a VM with a Ubuntu host machine - it is super slow.

I am currently trying to implement a plugin but the `magento s:d:c` command takes **6 minutes**.

Within [examples for Plugins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) it shows that you can set a 'disabled' var on a Plugin declaration. I guess this is only really to decativate inherited plugins, but it looks temptingly like it could also be used to deactivate/activate plugins quickly.

I experimented a bit and it seems like this is not the case, but then I was then curious, what would be best && safest way to activate/deactivate plugins as quickly as possible without having to compile every time?

I just really need to speed up this process as I need to switch this plugin off and on frequently in order to see what effects it has over default module functionality. Should I just comment all the methods in the interceptor?

If anyone is poised to tell me I should upgrade my setup, believe me I know, I have already a fair few hours on getting a Docker setup running but I have DB issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: afaik: plugins/the plugin list are compiled at least partly into generated/code, so while you can alter the content of plugins without `s:d:c` you need to do the commands again to disable/enable them.

Comment: Suspected as much, but I thought it was worth throwing it out there. As to the other question though, what is the safest way to deactivate an interceptor manually, or is there one?

Comment: I don't know of a safe way to do that.